# How to have two people working on a Visual Studio Solution/Projects?

Tags: svn

I work in a company where im working within Visual Studio 2008 (BIDS) to create SSRS reports.

Me and one other worker need to access the same Solution/Project structure within Visual Studio, ideally i would want it so that Visual Studio 'locks' a project in the same fashion that MS Office does to prevent other users opening it, but we can at least work within the same solution.

Whats the best way this can be done? I've done my research and pretty overwhelmed with options, i can only find source control solutions and no mention of a way to simply lock projects as such.

Here is what i've found:

- Visual Studio Team Services
- Visual SourceSafe
- VisualSVN
- AnkhSVN
- Visual Studio with Github integration extension

Are these solutions overkill for what i'm trying to achieve? If they are the only option i have please could someone recommend why you would choose one over the other.

Many thanks.
Jacob

Comment: I would go with the GitHub (Git) option.  The two of you could share a cloned repository two which only you would have access.  Visual Studio has a nice plugin for Git, so you would be covered there.

Comment: Thanks Tim - i'd like to see what others would recommend also before making a decision

Comment: The solution you listed, such as `svn`, and `git` is not intended to do a 'locking'. it is just a version control system which can easily solve the conflict when two ore more users edits the same file. and something like VisualSVN and AnkhSVN, Visual Studio with Github integration extension, is a client software of it.

Comment: To the point of @ymonad a VCS solution such as Git won't prevent both of you from working on the same file, but the common shared branch/repo would have to sync the work done by both of you.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no native ability in VS to lock projects when in use? I'm guessing Visual Studio Team Services is going to be the way forward then as it is specially designed for Visual Studio. Also, is there any benefit to an SVN-based solution such as VisualSVN?

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't work on a big project and there are only 2 developer I recommend VisualSVN.

VisualSVN is fast and easy to configure for small teams and also you can lock project.

1) Install VisualSVNServer

2) Creat your Repositories

3) Install Tortoise and VisualSVN on your local machine

4) Add your Solution to Repositories

Done!